# CharAt does not work in for loop

Tags: javascript

charAt "cannot read property"  when array[] is defined as i in the for for loop.

```
var array =["5seconds","1seconds","234seconds","57"];
        var time = ""

        for(var i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            time= array[i].charAt(0);
        }  

            document.write(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `for(var i=0;i<=4;i++)` which leads to an error in the last iteration. Change that to `for(var i=0;i<4;i++)` or `for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)`

```js
var array =["5seconds","1seconds","234seconds","57"]; 
var time = ""

for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    time= array[i].charAt(0);
    console.log(time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the document.write to inside the for loop allows the first index (0) to log of each string. Here is a snippet:

```js
var array =["5seconds","1seconds","234seconds","57"]; 
var time = "";
   
    for(var i=0;i< array.length;i++)
    {
       time = array[i].charAt(0)
       document.write(time); //goes inside the array, then it will log each 0 index
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is from 0 to 4, so at some moment you are trying to get the position 4 of your array, that does not exist. This is causing the error.
You should do this change on your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

And I think I should tell that this method of taking the time from a string is not very efficient. You are only getting the first digit using charAt(0).
An alternative would be to store in your array the following way:

```
var array = ["5 seconds", "1 seconds", "234 seconds"].
```

And then instead of taking the first character, you split the string in all the spaces, and get only the first position (0), which will be the number you want. Like this:

```
time = array.split(" ")[0].
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others pointed out your loop is going too far, the last index is the length-1, so if you have 4 elements the the last index is 3. Which is why it is best practice to  do either >= array.length -1 or > array.length.